# Moving files from one location to another with a wildcard file extension?

Tags: windows, powershell

Essentially I have a bunch of files that need to be moved. I have an index file that contains the correct file name, but the extensions are messed up. Is there a wildcard in Powershell to move over a file with any file extension if the names match??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `Move-Item C:\source\folder\foo.* D:\target\folder`?

Comment: There's also documentation on this you could read - [about_wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file names are in a file, one on each line, with no extension, this code might do it. When you are confident that the correct files will be moved, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
$names = Get-Content -Path '.\filelist.txt'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\the\directory' |
    ForEach-Item {
        if ($names -contains $_.Name) {
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\the\other\directory' -WhatIf
        }
    }
```